# RunTimeError: invalid memory adress or nil pointer deference in golang mailer

Tags: mongodb, go, email

Im Using https://github.com/kataras/go-mailer and https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

I somehow get this error:

```
[GIN] 2022/02/19 - 13:23:24 | 500 |   10.211394ms |             ::1 | POST     "/new-code?userid=kiddo&email=POG_CHAMP_EMAIL!"
Error Occuredcontext deadline exceeded

2022/02/19 13:23:35 [Recovery] 2022/02/19 - 13:23:35 panic recovered:
POST /new-code?userid=kiddo&email=HI_EMAIL_HERE? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Postman-Token: 07942c52-c661-46e9-a4c0-4eeb3c5bb6d1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:221 (0x104a406)
        panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:735 (0x104a3d6)
        sigpanic: panicmem()
/Users/gaurish/Desktop/Coding/SayHeyToMe-Emails/main.go:73 (0x169bfc7)
        main.func1: "code":    Insert.InsertedID,
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x14da441)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/recovery.go:99 (0x14da42c)
        CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x14d96a6)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/logger.go:241 (0x14d9689)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x14d8bf0)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/gin.go:555 (0x14d8858)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/Users/gaurish/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/gin.go:511 (0x14d8391)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2879 (0x12c393a)
        serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1930 (0x12befe7)
        (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581 (0x1065040)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

[GIN] 2022/02/19 - 13:23:35 | 500 |    3.428745ms |             ::1 | POST     "/new-code?userid=kiddo&email=I_HAD_EMAIL_HERE_KEKW?"
```

Here's mailer code: https://sourceb.in/25I37EgiF8 (It was 500 lines coz of html)

Here's the Router code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

func ping(client *mongo.Client, ctx context.Context) error {
    if err := client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("[MONGODB] Connected Successfully")
    return nil
}

func connect(uri string) (*mongo.Client, context.Context,
    context.CancelFunc, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),
        30*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(uri))
    return client, ctx, cancel, err
}

func close(client *mongo.Client, ctx context.Context,
    cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    defer cancel()
    defer func() {
        if err := client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    client, ctx, cancel, err := connect("MONGODB>>>>>>")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer close(client, ctx, cancel)
    ping(client, ctx)
    Database := client.Database("codes")
    CodesCollection := Database.Collection("Codes")
    r.POST("/new-code", func(c *gin.Context) {
        email := c.Query("email")
        Insert, err := CodesCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{
            {
                Key:   "userid",
                Value: c.Query("userid"),
            },
            {
                Key:   "used",
                Value: false,
            },
            {
                Key:   "expired",
                Value: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 6).Unix(),
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print("Error Occured")
            fmt.Print(err.Error())
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "success": true,
            "code":    Insert.InsertedID,
        })
        EmailUrl := "https://example.com"
        SendMail(email, EmailUrl)
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

What should i be doing? I'm using postman and that doesn't seem to a problem tho, Till yesterday i was just using it without the mail system and it worked properly, So probably won't be a mongodb problem at all.

Comment: Did you debug and see, `Insert.InsertedID` @line #73 might be nil

Comment: Add a check for `Insert` being nil before doing `Insert.InsertedID`

Comment: Insert.InsertedID isnt nil.

Comment: @Gaurish it won't be `nil` only if no error occurs. When your code encounters an error it should NOT continue as if nothing happened. When `InsertOne` returns an error then `Insert` will, very likely, be `nil`, and hence the line `"code": Insert.InsertedID` *will* panic.

Comment: @Gaurish Also, if your handler encounters an error it is bad style to return the `200` status code, which means success. Your handler should instead return an error status code. Usually a status code in one of the `400-499` or `500-599` ranges, depending on the error.

Comment: @Gaurish 98% of Go code that encounters an error should exit the surrounding function and NOT continue like nothing happened. Your handler should too.

Comment: Okay, What happens now is i get a plain empty body with 200.

Comment: @Gaurish edit the question to add the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the line here returns an error. So the `Insert` is `nil`.

```
Insert, err := CodesCollection.InsertOne(...)
```

That's why when you are calling `Insert.InsertedID` here,

```
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "success": true,
            "code":    Insert.InsertedID,
        })
```

The call to `Insert.InsertedID` is panicing with nil pointer reference exception.

To fix please add `return` to your error handling snippet to stop execution further:

```
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print("Error Occured")
            fmt.Print(err.Error())
            return
        }
```

Comment: I've tried this, After i added this, Whats gonna happen is: The server isnt gonna reply. The mail wont be sent. No error as well.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: No error, It didnt give any error.